# how to paste special insted of paste avery time when ctrl+v

Tags: vba, copy-paste, paste

Is there any way how to avoid paste and paste as value (paste special) any time when user want to paste?

Code that is called before Target was change? 
Code that is call after ctrl+v is pressed and before value is pasted..

I have a code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)   
Dim xValue As String 
Dim Dim xCheck1 As String
Dim xCheck2 As String

If Target.Count > 1 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.EnableEvents = False
xValue = Target.Value
On Error Resume Next
xCheck1 = Target.Validation.InCellDropdown
On Error GoTo 0
Application.Undo
On Error Resume Next
xCheck2 = Target.Validation.InCellDropdown
On Error GoTo 0
If xCheck1 = xCheck2 Then
    Target = xValue
Else
    ' Paste special - instead of paste
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This code should avoid pasting of list of values, code should paste just one value but it is not working properly. I'd like to copy value from another workbook and paste special any time when user pres ctrl+v.. I want to avoid automatic excel msgbox that write:

"The name 'List' already exist. Click Yes to use that version of the name, or click No to remane the version of List you're moving or copying".

Similar would be useful when don't want to rewrite data validation..

Thank you for any hepl.

Comment: Try looking up how to bind a macro to hotkeys that overwrite the original hotkeys. It will get you pointed in the right direction. This problem is fairly easy to solve, you will just need to do your research on how the hotkey bindings work. Also worth noting, you could simply do something like 'Application.DisplayAlerts = False' for the workbook. This does have some unintended consequences though since these alerts are displayed in numerous areas. Depending on who is using the macro, and how you trigger this setting, it could work well or could be risky.

Comment: thank you I will look how hotkeys works..